# Complex VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I managed to do a macro that is working for first 2 rows. How can I make the macro work for the rest of the rows (down to row 15 in this case)?

What I'm trying to achieve is:

Cell J2 =VLOOKUP($I3;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0) -VLOOKUP($I2;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)

I3 value fetched from Sheet2  minus I2 value fetched from Sheet2

Cell J3 = (VLOOKUP($I3;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)-1) / VLOOKUP($I2;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)

I3 value fetched from Sheet2 minus 1 divided by I2 value fetched from Sheet2

Cell J4 = VLOOKUP($I5;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0) -VLOOKUP($I4;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)

Cell J5 = (VLOOKUP($I5;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)-1) / VLOOKUP($I4;Sheet2!$I:$AA;MATCH(Sheet1!J1;Sheet2!$I$1:$AA$1;0);0)

The formula continues down to last row and to the right to last column. Lookup_value and column index are dynamic.

```
Sub VLookup()

Dim I As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim vlookup1 As Long
Dim vlookup2 As Long

   
 Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
 
      
I = 10
 
 While sh1.Cells(1, I) <> ""
         
        
        vlookup1 = Application.VLookup(sh1.Range("I3"), sh2.Range("I:AA"), Application.Match(sh1.Cells(1, I), sh2.Range("I1:AA1"), 0), 0)
        
        vlookup2 = Application.VLookup(sh1.Range("I2"), sh2.Range("I:AA"), Application.Match(sh1.Cells(1, I), sh2.Range("I1:AA1"), 0), 0)
        
              
       sh1.Cells(2, I) = vlookup1 - vlookup2
       sh1.Cells(3, I) = Format((vlookup1 - 1) / vlookup2, "0%")
            
I = I + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Your logic seems off.  Your vlookup is using cells i3 and i2, which will always return rows 3 and 2.  Your match is always going to return I.

Comment: Try explaining in words what you are trying to do, with some examples

Comment: So for next to rows lookup_value of the 1st vlookup would be I5 and for the 2n vlookup I4, then next two rows I7 and I6 etc. Does it make any sense?

Comment: sorry, but No, it doesn't.   Please **edit your question** with the details and examples I asked for. Eg "in cell xx I want a formula that returns [explain the calculation]"

Comment: What do you think now? :)

Comment: Makes sense now.  If I get a chance later I might propose a solution.   It would be nice to have sample data as text so I can copy paste to test on

Comment: Couple of other Q's: what version of Excel are you using (if it's 365 there are other possibilities) what do you want in the cells - the results of the calculation (as your current code is attempting to do ) or the formula itself?

Comment: How can provide sample file here?

Comment: Its Excel 365. The cells should only contain results like in my attempt/example. The actual data set is much bigger.  I can solve it with pure formulas but the file gets really slow.  I believe its over 600 rows and up to 52 columns for weeks. So many cells with Vlookup or Xlookup makes the file really slow

Comment: https://youtu.be/qB3fm1BwBwY    Tried using this video as inspiration but can't make it work.  What I'm trying to achieve is similar 2D VLOOKUP with difference that my solution requires two different lookups.